# Irrational number and Baire space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

How to show that the set of irrational numbers is a *Baire space* ?

Comment: There is an important distinction between two notions with very similar name. [The Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_%28set_theory%29) is a space on the set $\omega^\omega$, which is often used in descriptive set theory. This space is *homeomorphic* to irrational numbers (with the usual topology). And there is also a notion of a [Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space), which means, roughly speaking: *A space in which the Baire category theorem holds.* Maybe you should clarify your question and explain which of these two meanings you are asking about.

Comment: I have added ([tag:baire-category]) tag, which is suitable if you question is whether the irrationals are *a Baire space*. If your question is how to show that irrationals are homeomorphic to *the Baire space* $\omega^\omega$, then ([tag:descriptive-set-theory]) might be a more suitable tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak A third similarly-named notion: as a subset of $\mathbb R$, the set of irrational numbers has *the property of Baire*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's see. The definition of a Baire space is that a countable intersection of dense open sets is dense. So let $I$ be the space of irrational numbers, and let $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$ be a sequence of dense open subsets of $I$; I have to show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense. Now, "$U$ is open in $I$" means that $U=V\cap I$ for some $V$ which is open in $\mathbb R$; moreover, if $V\cap I$ is dense in $I$, then (since $I$ is dense in $\mathbb R$) it's dense in $\mathbb R$, and so is $V$. So it's enough to show is that, if $V_1,V_2,\dots$ is a sequence of dense open sets in $\mathbb R$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty(V_n\cap I)=(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n)\cap I$ is dense. But $I$ itself is a countable intersection of dense open subsets of $\mathbb R$, namely, $I=\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R\setminus\{q\})$. So now I have to show that $(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n)\cap\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R\setminus\{q\})$ is dense, but that's a countable intersection of dense open subsets of $\mathbb R$, so by the Baire category theorem . . .

Comment: Let me ask you the following question: you have shown that the last intersection is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, right? But we have to show that it is dense in $I$? Maybe I am missing smth?

Comment: @ZFR Since $I$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, a subset of $I$ which is dense in $\mathbb R$ is also dense in $I$.

Comment: Let $G\subset I$ which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then $\overline{G}=\mathbb{R}$. Then its closure in $I$ is $\overline{G}\cap I=\mathbb{R}\cap I=I$, which means that $G$ is dense in $I$. Right?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

The Baire category theorem gives sufficient conditions for a topological space to be a Baire space. It is an important tool in topology and functional analysis.
    (BCT1) Every complete metric space is a Baire space. More generally, every topological space which is homeomorphic to an open subset of a complete pseudometric space is a Baire space. In particular, every completely metrizable space is a Baire space.
    (BCT2) Every locally compact Hausdorff space is a Baire space.
    BCT1 shows that each of the following is a Baire space:
    The space R of real numbers;
    The space of irrational numbers;
    The Cantor set;
    Indeed, every Polish space;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space

another definition :

A topological space X in which each subset of X of the "first category" has an empty interior. A topological space which is homeomorphic to a complete metric space is a Baire space, ,where terminology homeomorphic :

two objects are homeomorphic if they can be deformed into each other by a continuous, invertible mapping

Comment: I would say showing the topology on the irrationals is completely metrizeable is overkill for this question.

Comment: but Baire space requires it  right?

Comment: I just mean that you can utilize the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is completely metrizeable, hence Baire, which is a more standard fact.

Comment: The essential point being that, in order to get from the irrationals to $\mathbb{R}$, you only need to add in countably many singletons (the rational numbers). And singletons are, in particular, closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with empty interior.

Comment: i meant should i delete my answer as non relevant?

Comment: Your answer is fine, just not the most efficient one possible. Here, I've given you an upvote.

Comment: yes of course,because i am not expert on spaces,thanks very much