# Yes/No : Is irrational number $(\mathbb{Q}^c$ ) are baires space?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Is irrational number ( $\mathbb{Q}^c$ ) are   baires space ? yes/no

i got the links [Irrational number and Baire space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637791/irrational-number-and-baire-space)

But  i didn't  understand  the   answer properly

My Proof : By the Baire Category Theorem, a space that is homeomorphic to a complete metric space must be a Baire Space: the intersection of a countable family of open dense sets must be dense. But $\mathbb{Q^c}$ does not have this property, because it is uncountable and no point is isolated: for each $p\in\mathbb{Q^c}$, let $C_{p }= \mathbb{Q^c}\setminus\{p\}$. This is open (since $\{p\}$ is closed  in $\mathbb{R}$, hence in the induced topology of $\mathbb{Q^c}$) and dense, since every open ball with center in $\mathbb{p}$ intersects $C_p$. But 
$$\bigcap_{p\in\mathbb{Q^c}} C_p = \emptyset$$
is not dense. Hence $\mathbb{Q^c}$ is not a Baire space.

Comment: ?? $\Bbb Q^\complement$ is *not* countable

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen    yes  sir  ,im thinking now

Comment: Not to mention that the referenced question is why the irrationals *are* a Baire space

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  sir i have edits  its

Comment: Everything you wrote in your proof is true until the last sentence.  Since $\mathbb{Q}^c$ is uncountable, then $\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{Q}^c} C_p$ is not a *countable* intersection of dense open sets, hence you have not shown that $\mathbb{Q}^c$ is not Baire.  (And in fact, it *is* Baire.)

Comment: @NateEldredge   complement  of uncountable is counatble

Comment: @jasmine: Well, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable subset of the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}$, so its complement $\mathbb{Q}^c$ must surely be uncountable.  (It is possible, however, for an uncountable set to have an uncountable complement: consider the complement of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$.)